# Best way to benchmark Drupal stack performance

Tags: 6, performance

I recently asked a [question regarding Drupal performance](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/best-way-to-optimize-for-authenticated-user-performance) and got some great replies.

This got me thinking, **what is a reliable/meaningful way to benchmark Drupal?**

It's easy to say "install APC, memchached & Varnish" or "install module x or y", but how can I quantify just how big of a performance gain I'm getting from each setup? Basically, a sure-fire way to compare setups and find bottlenecks to squeeze the most possible performance from a Drupal site. What is the best method to find out?

Targetting Drupal 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like jmeter, http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter

It allows actual benchmarking of authenticated sessions, which many of the other approaches like ab do not. There's an article about using jmeter with authenticated users at [this link](http://www.agileapproach.com/blog-entry/using-jmeter-test-performance-drupal-authenticated-users)

Comment: thanks for that i'm gonna check it out, still early to close this one though! :)

Comment: Agreed with rfay, Jmeter is really a good tool to benchmark your application.

Comment: rfay, just wondering if we can use the -C name=value ( the cookie option ) some way in ab to simulate authenticated user basically make drupal bypass the cache?

Comment: I would imagine that you can *use* the cookie, but getting it created in the first place is where jquery knows what to do. You have to log in and capture the cookie, and then continue to use it.

Comment: JMeter's a great suggestion.  I've published another Drupal test plan and some plotting tools: http://www.metaltoad.com/taxonomy/term/195