# Best APC settings to reduce page execution time

Tags: 7, performance, caching

I have Drupal 7, apc with php-fpm and apache behind varnish and512 MB RAM.

I measure page execution time with devel module.

Database query time is low (62ms) compared to page execution time which is 854 ms.
That means there is problem with PHP and APC settings.

My current settings are just

```
apc.shm_size = 64
apc.stat=1
```

How I can improve?

What are the best settings for Drupal given the above configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We run in a SVN push environment so we only clear the apc file cache with a script.

APC settings:

```
apc.ttl=604800
apc.user_ttl=3600
apc.shm_size=192M
apc.include_once_override=1
auto_globals_jit=Off
apc.num_files_hint = 2048

apc.stat_ctime = 0
apc.file_update_protection = 2
apc.stat = 0
```

PHP Script:

```
<?php
$return = apc_clear_cache('opcode');
echo var_export($return);
```

604800 = 1 week.

After this, [getting xdebug/xhprof up and running](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/what-all-contributes-to-drupal-page-execution-time) and doing a cache grind of the site should let you know what's slowing down the site. In short analyzing the cache grind output is the best way to speed up Drupal. Below I'm listing what patches and modules we use to speed it up; in your case it will be different most likely.

**Drupal 6 Specific Answer Below**

Once you get past this point and realize the APC isn't going to give you what your looking for, switch to [pressflow](https://launchpad.net/pressflow) and give these patches a whirl:

- [Core - Cache module_implements()](http://drupal.org/node/557542#comment-4989990)
- [Imagecache - use lock.inc instead of a file lock](http://drupal.org/node/1243258#comment-4850634)
- [Views - views_get_default_view() - race conditions and memory usage](http://drupal.org/node/853864#comment-5011194)
- [Views - Persistent caching for unpack_options() calls from building displays](http://drupal.org/node/402944#comment-4650020)

Also try some of these modules as they improved our sites speed in a big way:

- [Imageinfo Cache](http://drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache)
- [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](http://drupal.org/project/advagg)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I have Drupal 7.

Comment: So take the APC parts and the xdebug/xhprof parts and look at the D6 patches as an example of what to look for in the d.o issue queue. All of the above patches where a result of looking at the cache grind, finding the pain point and finding the corresponding issue for it. Quick start: http://drupal.org/project/issues/search/drupal?status%5B%5D=Open&version%5B%5D=7.x&issue_tags=Performance

Comment: There is a drupal 7 performance wiki now: http://groups.drupal.org/node/210683

Comment: Just FYI, I had to comment the line apc.include_once_override=1 because broke the site  http://puregin.org/node/2550/3928

Comment: http://php.net/apc.configuration#ini.apc.include-once-override
Thanks for pointing that out. Depending on the PHP and APC version it might cause problems

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those "how long is a piece of string questions".

What is good for a high-volume site may not be the same for a low-volume site with a lot of modules, and may not be the same for a medium-volume site with only a few modules enabled.  Other sites running on the server may also be eating into the memory that APC has available.

My starting point is

```
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.shm_size=64
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.rfc1867=1
```

I then adjust the settings for the server, but again, there is no one size fits all set of settings.

Find apc.php (probably located at /usr/share/pear/apc.php), and install it in the DOCROOT for your Drupal install.  Lock it down to your IP address via Apache config.  Edit the username/password inside, and then browse to it.  You will then see your APC stats.

Reconfigure the shm_size parameter to minimize cache misses.  Ideally, you want to give it just enough memory to never have a cache miss for a file, plus some additional memory for the APC user cache.

Optimize TTL to prevent cache churning.  If you aren't editing files, you can bump up this number.

enable_cli is handy when you use drush a lot, so that drush uses the cached files from APC.

rfc1867 is handy for file uploads.

I also noticed the php-fpm in the title.  This complicates matters, and is really beyond the scope of Drupal Answers.  You may get better responses at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), as a lot of the system configuration settings don't pertain to Drupal directly.

Comment: where is some good tutorial that explains in easy language what each settings is doing, like ttl, segments, etc? how cli helps with drush?

Comment: Could you please explain how "traffic I get, what else is running on the server, what modules I have installed, etc." affect the settings? thanks

Comment: these settings above did not help a lot. Should I try xhprof to see what happens with php?

Comment: All of the APC settings are described at http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php

Comment: I read the manual but I still have questions. 1.what's the difference between apc.ttl and apc.user_ttl? 2. How I will decide about its value? I did not understand how to set num_files_hint. 3.Is it safe to turn on enable_cli?

Comment: I just copy pasted your settings and I failed like every time I just copy paste settings that work from others. I have this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723316/warning-require-once-function-require-once-unable-to-allocate-memory-for-po . So how to find optimal ttl?

Comment: @MPD > enable_cli is handy when you use drush a lot, so that drush uses the
> cached files from APC. Actually, the cli is a separate process and doesn't share its apc cache with apache, or even between calls to drush.

Comment: @RobinMillette Yes, that is correct.  I set this to prevent some warning messages on some setups about APC not being enabled.

Answer (score 2):

APC just improves loading and parsing of PHP files. A large part is also the execution time itself. There are many factors that can increase the execution time, including bugs (especially cache related bugs), internal overhead (e.g. drupal_alter(), module_implements()) and so on.

As you asked and was already suggested by mikeytown2, I'd use xhprof (I prefer it over xdebug these days as it provides direct, quick access to the result and requires no additional tools) to find out where your bottlenecks are.

I've recently written two blog posts about [using xhprof within Drupal](http://techblog.md-systems.ch/tutorial_howto/finding-performance-bottlenecks-xhprof-0) and [typical bottlenecks](http://techblog.md-systems.ch/tutorial_howto/typical-performance-bottlenecks-patterns), which you might find interesting.

Comment: http://groups.drupal.org/node/82889 PHP profiling with XHprof