# Website is getting very high load due to "UPDATE cache SET data..."

Tags: database

It's a high traffic website, but I guess high load is not because of traffic because many times it runs smooth on same traffic. I researched a lot and optimized Apache, switched off logging modules to save resources and done whatever may be cause of load.
Then finally I installed devel on site and check using "Collect query info", "Display query log" and I found that this particular query taking too much time (more than 2000 ms)

```
UPDATE cache SET data = 'a:2:{s:7:\"profile\";a:36545:{s:32:\"c21f969b5f03d33d43e04f8f136e7682\";a:17:{s:6:\"layout\";s:7:\"default\";s:14:\"layout_desktop\";s:7:\"default\";s:15:\"layout_handheld\";s:2:\"-1\";s:13:\"layout_iphone\";s:2:\"-1\";s:4:\"menu\";s:13:\"primary-links\";s:10:\"menu_style\";s:4:\"mega\";s:11:\"option_font\";s:1:\"0\";s:14:\"option_layouts\";s:1:\"0\";s:11:\"option_menu\";s:1:\"0\";s:13:\"option_screen\";s:1:\"1\";s:13:\"option_t3logo\";s:1:\"1\";s..........................................................
```

and page getting loaded and loaded to infinite time, it never completes.
I am sure this is the only reason for high load on server.

APC is already installed on my seerver.

Comment: High load website and DB cache is a bad bad idea. Why not APC, Memcached or any other in-memory caching?

Comment: I suggest you optimize Mysql and also use APC php plugin for Apache.

Comment: Hello Molot, thanks for quick reply. but APC is already installed. Its the only query creating problem and also I am using Boost for caching.

Comment: @user2446908 nice. So why you refuse to use it for cache? Also, add @ in front of my name if you want me to be notified about your comments

Comment: thanks @Mołot for the tip, I am quite new. Please explain "why you refuse to use it for cache", how can I add it to cache

Comment: If it's a question about performance of one query, it's off-topic here, and should be asked on Stack Overflow or Server Fault. So I answered from the perspective it might be on-topic, "what to do when Drupal's DB cache is too slow for it's load?".

Answer (score 1):

Given your server already has APC installed, you do not need to keep cache in database at all. And probably shouldn't.

Install [APC module](https://drupal.org/project/apc) (for older Drupal versions see [Cacherouter](https://drupal.org/project/cacherouter) or [Cache Backport](https://drupal.org/project/cache_backport)) to move your cache from MySQL to RAM. Without it, APC only caches opcode, not Drupal's cache data. Also, [APC Status](https://drupal.org/project/apc_status) or [APC Admin](https://drupal.org/project/apc_admin) module helps with monitoring.

It might be wise to exclude form cache from APC and keep it in database, but that's material for another question.

For APC optimization, see [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/12534/16495).

Comment: thanks. but APC is not available for D6 should  I install cache_backport module. And after installing this should I disable drupal core cache and aggregate css & js options.

Comment: @user2446908 No, after installing it keep Drupal's setting as they were. It will simply move Drupal's cache to a more efficient place, so do not disable it :)

Comment: should I install cache_backport for D6?

Comment: @user2446908 if you want to go for cache in RAM, then yes. Is this a good way for you? Your choice. I would, probably. But I do not know your setup as well as you do.

Comment: OK I will try it, but why its only stuck on this particular query, Is there any way to stop this query or should I check my mysql config?

Comment: @user2446908 From Drupal side, only way to stop this query from happening is to get rid of caching (stupid on loaded site) or switch to no-SQL caching, for example like I described above. And if you want to make your MySQL accept this query, then it is off-topic here, it belongs to Server Fault or Stack Overflow - simple update of one column should not kill anything.

Comment: but I am still wondering why sometimes everything run smoothly and why Its stuck sometimes. Sometimes clearing the cache do the trick and sometime makes me frustrated to do all sort of hit and try and it continues for some days. I am still unable to find the root cause. all the time it overloaded only this query stuck

Comment: @user2446908 And it's still a question for Server Fault, why your MySQL server does not like this one query...

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: @user2446908 I think Mołot has been quite forthcoming with what you need to do - this is a MySQL/server performance issue, one that isn't inherently related to Drupal (if you have evidence to the contrary of that, please provide it), so it's off-topic here. We cannot provide you with ongoing support in comments, nor support problems with your server config here, as this is a Q+A site for questions solely about Drupal. Thanks for your understanding

Comment: @Mołot and Clive I understand. And wont go off topic. Its related to Drupal because this query is too long(hundreds of pages of MS word) even when tried to see with tail command (last 100 lines of slow_query.log) its going on printing and not ending. I dont know how to post that query here, Please help.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how anyone could help you any further here - the answer is simply that your site is trying to cache too much at once. Why exactly that might be depends on literally dozens of different, potentially complicated, factors. These factors could be your Drupal site, the modules installed, your server config, DBMS config, how much memory you've got, how much hard drive space is available, and on and on and on. If you've got to the end of your debugging abilities, it's time to get a Drupal contractor involved.

Comment: Either way, I'm afraid we can't continue to allow you to use the comments here like a support ticket. It goes against the very ethos of this site, and it's not fair on other users. I understand you have an issue you need to get resolved, but I'm afraid this isn't the right place for this particular issue. Please see the [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on what we do here. Thanks