# Does adding more processing power increases Drupal Page Load Speed

Tags: performance

I have a site hosted on Acquia Cloud.all the unnecessary modules are uninstalled. The site has only couple of nodes (300 almost)and lot of imported registered accounts.
Below optimizations are enabled already

http://www.goodykitchen.com

1. memcache
2. varnish
3. CDN - Cloudfront
4. Page Caching (Drupal's Default)
5. CSS / JS aggregation

RAM : 1.7GB
CPU : 1 ECU

**Problem:**

My comparison site is bbcgoodfood.com in terms of page load. I have gone through some research and they are using most of above mentioned optimizations. Is there a way to find out why their page load is so smooth. OR should i just increase the Cloud size and see my site page load. (currently i do not have many users on the site)

any clues ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

APC might be your answer

[Best APC settings to reduce page execution time](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12534/best-apc-settings-to-reduce-page-execution-time)

There's a lot here on Drupal speed and performance generally ...