# Improving template/rendering performance

Tags: views, theming, commerce, performance

I'm running a Drupal [commerce](http://drupal.org/project/commerce) site and using Views to display up to 30  product node teasers per page.  The product display content type has a several fields (image, desc, manufacturer) and I am also using the [flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag) so that users can mark favorite products. As a result, the query ends up being fairly large with several joins.

Views statistics reveal that despite the complex query, the slow page loads are due to the rendering time it takes...

```
Query build time    21.13 ms
Query execute time  1.67 ms
View render time    4237.2 ms
```

How do I improve my Drupal template/rendering performance to get my pages to load faster?

Comment: Are your views being cached, and are you using MEMCACHE or some similar optimiser?

Comment: No, views cannot be cached as each teaser rendered contains an add-to-cart form which doesn't work if cached. The HTML includes a form token specific to the original session / page view used to generate the HTML, it will be invalid once it's been cached.

Answer (score 4):

I would check for File IO; what does [profiling your site](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/what-all-contributes-to-drupal-page-execution-time/1025#1025) tell you. I had similar issues and created the http://drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache module and my views performance improved a lot by reducing file IO.

Seeing that your on shared hosing, checkout this http://kpayne.me/2012/02/04/use-register_tick_function-to-profile-your-code/

Comment: Thank @mikeytown2. I'm also on Drupal 7.  Will check out the link.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of the more obvious tips:

1. Enable caching for your Drupal.
2. Optimize your Drupal database.
   Log in to your Drupal admin area and go to Site Configuration > Performance. Besides enabling cache, you should also enable Page compression, Optimize CSS files and Optimize JavaScript files.
3. If your Drupal is hosted on a dedicated solution, you can [modify the global MySQL settings for better performance](http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_optimize_Drupal_website_hosted_on_VPSDedicated_server.html).
4. *More for front-side micro-optimisation, you can check your website using [this online tool](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/). It will give you valuable information on what modifications can be made in order to improve its performance.
5. Of course, disable/remove all modules/blocks you are not using.

Now, most of those are pretty basic and usual optimisations. I assume this is where you are now standing.

**Next steps:**

In my (humble) opinion, you would get way better response times if you install [APC](http://drupal.org/project/apc) or [Memcache](http://drupal.org/project/memcache) on your server. There is also [varnish](http://drupal.org/project/varnish) I have heard lots of good things about,  but I have not had the chance yet to play with it, and it looks like it is meant for anonymous sessions and static pages so I am not certain you would gain as much benefits than from other 2 above mentionned modules.

If you want to see benchmarks of a Drupal instance with/without APC caching, [see here](http://static.zend.com/topics/Optimizing-Drupal-Performance-Zend-Acquia-Whitepaper-Feb2010v2.pdf).

Last but not least, have you tried benchmarking *without the flag module* to see what impact this module has? We had to rewrite some queries of the like in other 3rd party modules a few times, some of the sql Drupal generates is not really optimised as you probably realised by now.

Happy coding, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the well-written answer. This site is on a shared host unfortunately. So, I have no access to modify MySQL settings and cannot use APC on this particular host. A quick test of removing the flag module doesn't seem to have significant impact, but I'll have to do more thorough testing later.